# Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket

Tags: android, spring-boot, ffmpeg, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a video file to the server(`Spring Boot`) from android.

A video filmed with the phone has >50 MB if you film at least 2 minutes so I have to compress the file before uploading.
Before compressing I tried to upload uncompressed files  and it worked fine(10-30MB videos). Now I want to compress files because I want to send bigger videos to the server.
I use multipart/form-data in android to send the file to the server.

**EDIT:**

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            progressDialog.show();
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(getApplicationContext(), data.getData());

                    ///get the name of file without extension
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(filePath);
                    int start = filePath.lastIndexOf('.');
                    stringBuilder.delete(start, filePath.length());
                    //--------------
                    //get file extension(e.g mp4)
                    File file = new File(filePath);
                    String contentType = getFileType(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    //--------------
                    //create compressed file path=initial file path+ _compressed+(random nr.)+ extension .mp4
                    Random random = new Random();
                    int fileNr = random.nextInt(999);
                    String compressedFilePath = stringBuilder.toString() + "_compressed" + fileNr +"."+ contentType;

                    //compress file from gallery and save it with the above name
                    String[] command = {"-y", "-i", filePath, "-s", "640x480", "-r", "25", "-vcodec",
                            "mpeg4", "-b:v", "150k", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", compressedFilePath};
                    executeFFmpegBinary(command);

                    File file2 = new File(compressedFilePath);

                    if (file2.exists()) {
                        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
                        RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(contentType), file2);
                        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                                .addFormDataPart("type", contentType)
                                .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file", file2.getName(), fileBody)
                                .build();
                        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                .url(SERVER_ADDRESS_UPLOAD)
                                .post(requestBody)
                                .build();
                        try {
                            final Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                                printFromThread(response.toString());
                                throw new IOException("Error: " + response);
                            } else {
                                printFromThread(response.body().string());
                            }
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }

            });
            thread.start();
        }

    }
```

When I use FFmpeg compression and I send the compressed file to the server I receive the following error in the server:`Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket`

Server bean:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/upload-image", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody
   public String handleUploadImageRequest(@RequestParam("uploaded_file") 
   MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
File fileReceived = new File(VIDEOS_DIR+"/"+file.getOriginalFilename());
fileReceived.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileReceived);
fileOutputStream.write(file.getBytes());
fileOutputStream.close();

prelucrareVideo(fileReceived);
return "....";
```

}

Here is the exception:

```
2017-05-22 23:36:24.122 DEBUG 5032 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
2017-05-22 23:36:24.122 DEBUG 5032 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
2017-05-22 23:36:24.123 DEBUG 5032 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
2017-05-22 23:36:24.123 DEBUG 5032 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : Could not complete request

org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:111) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:79) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1100) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:932) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2874) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1110) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:75) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2801) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1110) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:75) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:717) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:40) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1061) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:319) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:627) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:342) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:881) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2801) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1110) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:75) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 23 more

2017-05-22 23:36:24.130 ERROR 5032 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket] with root cause

java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:717) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:40) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1061) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:319) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:627) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:342) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:881) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2801) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1110) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:75) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
```

What is the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What has compressing to do with this all? There is no compressing in your code. You are trying to upload a file i think. Is it a valid file?

Comment: And yes. It'a  valid file I pick videos from gallery and send them to the server

Comment: ??? The file you pick from the gallery will be a valid file yes. But then you are gone crop to a new file. Which you then upload. Is that file a valid file?

Comment: I dont understand that you crop a file just before upload. Just crop it first and check if it is a valid file. Then upload later.

Comment: `I pick videos from gallery and send them to the server `. You are not doing that. You crop them and send the cropped result to the server.

Comment: You are right. I pick a video from gallery. Get the absolute path and then create another file adding "Compress" to the initial absolute path. So the path to the new file is initial path+ "compress". Then I send the compressed file(using the above path) to the server. I think that the file is valid because I can see it in my phone. So the compressed file is created (2-4 MB)

Comment: I receive in android this exception: expected 1979 bytes but received 8192 android

Comment: Start debugging without compression. Just upload a compressed file. And if you post figures then tell where they come from and comment on them self first.

Comment: `filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)`? You mean `file2.getName()` ?

Comment: What is the value of `contentType`? And file2.getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: content type is always .mp4 as the extension of the picked gallery video

Comment: I edited my question. I changed the android part. I made it more clear with  comments

Comment: So if I keep the code like this I get an error : expected 1979 bytes but received 8192 android

Comment: You should not keep the code like this. You should just upload a compressed file. I said that before. And where do you get that message? How can the word android be in it? How would the server know about android?

Comment: And .mp4 is not a valid content type of course. You cannot use a file extension for a content type.

Comment: When I debug the android application when I excute this line:                             final Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute(); I receive that exception

Comment: But where? Do you catch it? And why is it an error first and now an exception? Come to the point! Logcat?

Comment: I don't understand something you said : "You should just upload a compressed file". This are the steps I do: 1) Get into gallery 2) Pick a video 3) get the path of the video 4) create a new path for the future compressed video 5)compress the video and save it using the path from 4) step 6) send the compressed video using that path to the server ....sometimes it works but the video compress can't open or I get that error as response

Comment: Check this out: http://imgur.com/a/ePHzq . Why can' t I open first video? What is the problem?